# VBScript: How to select text after 6th occurence of char?

Tags: vbscript

I have this string:

```
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

I need to return the text after the 6th occurence of `|` and before the 7th. In this example, it would be `6`.

Can his be achieved using the simple String functions (Mid, Left, Right, InStr)?

Comment: You are looking for [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: @Filburt I can't use Split unfortunately.

Comment: You should explicitly state why `Split("0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9")(6)` is not an option for you and provide sample data that clearly demonstrates you constraints. Also your title suggests that your desired result is the *text after 6th occurrence of char* which would be `6|7|8|9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, you could use a RegExp to look for the possibly empty sequence of non-| **before** a | and **after** 6 such sequences:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "^(?:[^\|]*\|){6}([^\|]*)\|"
>> WScript.Echo r.Execute("0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9")(0).SubMatches(0)
>>
6
```

For production code, you'd need a check against non-confirming data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s, c, n, i, p, e, r

s = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" ' examined string
c = "|" ' split char
n = 6 ' occurance to start from

i = 0
p = 0
r = ""
Do
    p = InStr(p + 1, s, c)
    If p = 0 Then Exit Do
    i = i + 1
    If i = n Then
        e = InStr(p + 1, s, c)
        If e > 0 Then r = Mid(s, p + 1, e - p - 1)
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

MsgBox r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9"

For i = 1 To 6
    intPos1 = InStr(intPos1 + 1, s, "|")
    If intPos1 = 0 Then Exit For
Next

If intPos1 > 0 Then
    intPos2 = InStr(intPos1 + 1, s, "|")
    If intPos2 > intPos1 Then MsgBox Mid(s, intPos1 + 1, intPos2 - intPos1 - 1)
End If
```

Or, like @Filburt said, it could be a one-liner with `Split()`:

```
MsgBox Split(s, "|")(6)
```